# What do we call the object which stores the functional interface definition and defined through lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, functional-interface

What should we call the object which stores the implementation of this functional interface? Would calling it an anonymous class be correct?

Functional interface definition

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface IntBinaryOperator {
  int applyAsInt(int left, int right);
}
```

Test class used to implement the functional interface

```
public class Lambdas {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntBinaryOperator multiply = (a, b) -> a * b; // what is this object called?
    System.out.println(multiply.applyAsInt(2,3));
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to clean up your example with standard types.

Comment: There is really no special name for it. But calling it "anonymous class" is wrong. Anonymous class can be compared to the lambda expression itself (i.e., the on-the-fly code implementing the interface). The JLS simply calls it object/instance. There are cases where an object like `mul` is referred to as a "closure", but that's typically when there are captured values involved.

Answer (score 5):

> Evaluation of a lambda expression produces an instance of a functional interface (§9.8). —[JLS 15.27](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27)

If you're asking about a name for the bytes representing the code `imul; ret N`, that's a *lambda body* (15.27.2).